# bash script fails to read first line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a script to convert timestamps into seconds so I can eventually work out the averages. I noticed that the number of output lines did not equal the amount of input lines. In fact it does not seem to read the first line. I simplified the code to check it but it is the same every time.

Input file looks like this:

```
00:00:01
00:00:02
00:00:03
```

Output like this:

```
00 00 02
00 00 03
```

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    awk -F: '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' > /home/time.log

done < /home/timestamp.log
```

I'm sure it is something stupid but I cannot see it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a loop. You can simply use awk:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' /home/timestamp.log > /home/time.log
```

The reason for the behaviour you see is that you don't pass the `line` to awk. So the first line is read by *read* the loop and rest by awk inside the loop as awk gets it *stdin* from the loop. Hence, you don't see the first line.

If it's still not clear, just add a `echo "Hello"` *after* the `awk` call inside your loop and see how many times it gets printed :)

You probably intended to do:

```
echo $line | awk -F: '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' > /home/time.log
```

But that's just unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

`read line` is consuming the first line of the input, and assigning it to the Bash variable `$line`, which you then ignore. Then the body of the loop is processing the rest of the file using awk.

You can just use `awk` directly without the loop:

```
awk -F: '{ print $1, $2, $3 }' /home/timestamp.log > /home/time.log
```

Or you can use a loop and not awk:

```
while IFS=: read h m s; do echo $h $m $s >> /home/time.log; done < /home/timestamp.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tr` to your advantage here:

```
tr ':' ' ' < /home/timestamp.log
```

It will provide the translation of characters you need. E.g.:

```
$ tr ':' ' ' <dat/timestamp.log
00 00 01
00 00 02
00 00 03
```